# Deletion in Berkeley DB

Tags: java, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I am not very familiar with Berkeley DB . I was trying to delete an entry from database.
 i am able to insert to the database and view the database.
For viewing entries i used the command

```
   symbolsByName.subIndex(symbolName).entities();
```

where symbolsByName is a secondary index and symbolName is the search string.

for deletion i used this command.

```
   boolean b=symbolsByName.delete(symbolName);
```

the function returned true value. But that entry is still in the databse.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @amirouche  I am using java